# Does probability increase over time if data stays the same

Tags: probability

The example is violent crimes in america. In 2012 data showed that one in 1 in about 250 people were exposed to some type of violent crime that year.  If data stays the same for the next fifty years, is my probability of being exposed to a violent crime over that whole 50 year period still 1 in 250? Or does it increase as the years go by without being exposed to to any violent crime. My chances stay the same correct?

Comment: This feels more like a sociological question than a mathematical one.

Comment: I could see that. Obviously many factors will change over such a long period, but if they theoretically stayed the same.

Comment: If nothing changes, then nothing changes.

Comment: @IanColey: He has stated the assumptions and specified the actual mathematical question he intends. This is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on where you stand while asking this question. If you are asking what is the probability of being exposed at least once in the next 50 years, then the answer is as @ShreevatsaR calculated. On the other hand, imagine that you have luckily spent 49 years without being exposed and now you are wondering what are the chances of remaining safe one more year, it is still $249/250$ (under the assumption of independence).

Comment: Realistically (without the independence and/or uniform distribution assumptions), it's probably a lot higher than that: if you've survived 49 years, then we can infer that you (or your circumstances) are low-risk, so probably your chances of an event are even less than 1 in 250. Of course, by "over that whole 50-year period", this is probably not the question intended anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose a person, in a year, has a probability $\dfrac{1}{250}$ of being exposed (to violent crime).

Then the probability that he is *not* exposed in a certain year is $1 - \dfrac1{250}$, so the probability of not being exposed all $50$ years is $\left(1 - \dfrac1{250}\right)^{50}$, and the probability of being exposed at least once in the $50$ years is therefore 
$$1 - \left(1 - \dfrac1{250}\right)^{50} \approx \frac{50}{250} = \frac{1}{5}$$
(the [exact value](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1+-+%281+-+1%2F250%29%5E50) is $0.1815975\dots$, rather than $1/5 = 0.20$).

Note the assumptions involved here:

- Any given person has a probability $1/250$ of being exposed. This is an *inference* from the statistics that $1/250$th of the population got exposed to crime, but not necessarily a valid one: perhaps it is that one in $250$ people is high-risk and very likely to be exposed in a given year, while the other $249/250$ fraction of people are unlikely to be exposed even given $50$ years. (This assumption is equivalent to saying that every person has a uniformly random chance of being exposed, i.e. it's not that some people are more likely than others.)
- The crime rate stays the same for the entire $50$-year period.
- For any given person, exposure in one year is independent of exposure in another. This need not be true (e.g. people are likely to die before the $50$ years is past; perhaps those exposed one year are more likely to be exposed another).

All these assumptions are not valid in the real world, but that's the answer to the mathematical question under the simplistic assumptions.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: You're right ($50/250$ is only approximate probability, though it's the exact expected value), I've rewritten the answer.